# Data generation: Creating a vector of vectors

Tags: r

I have a vector of positive integers of unknown length. Let's call it vector a with elements a[1], a[2], ...

I want to perform calculations on vector b where for all i, 0 <= b[i] <= a[i].

The following does not work:

```
for(b in 0:a)
{
  # calculations
}
```

The best I have come up with is:

```
probabilities <- function(a,p)
{
  k <- a
  k[1] <- 1
  h <- rep(0,sum(a)+1)
  for(i in 2:length(a))
  {
    k[i] <- k[i-1]*(a[i-1]+1)
  }
  for(i in 0:prod(a+1))
  {
    b <- a
    for(j in 1:length(a))
    {
      b[j] <- (floor(i/k[j]) %% (a[j]+1))
    }
    t <- 1
    for(j in 1:length(a))
    {
      t <- t * choose(a[j],b[j])*(p[j])^(b[j])*(1-p[j])^(a[j]-b[j])
    }
    h[sum(b)+1] <- h[sum(b)+1] + t
  }
  return(h)
}
```

In the middle of my function is where I create b. I start off by setting b equal to a (so that it is the same size). Then, I replace all of the elements of b with different elements that are rather tricky to calculate. This seems like an inefficient solution. It works, but it is fairly slow as the numbers get large. Any ideas for how I can cut down on process time? Essentially, what this does for b is the first time through, b is all zeros. Then, it is 1, 0,0,0,... The first element keeps incrementing until it reaches a[1], then b[2] increments and b[1] is set to 0. Then b[1] starts incrementing again.

I know the math is sound, I just do not trust that it is efficient. I studied combinatorics for a few years, but have never studied computational complexity theory, so coming up with a fast algorithm is a bit beyond my realm of knowledge. Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: They are supposed to be, yes. An example: a <- c(2,1,2), then I have the following possible values for b:

c(0,0,0)
c(1,0,0)
c(2,0,0)
c(0,1,0)
c(1,1,0)
c(2,1,0)
c(0,0,1)
c(1,0,1)
c(2,0,1)
c(0,1,1)
c(1,1,1)
c(2,1,1)
c(0,0,2)
c(1,0,2)
c(2,0,2)
c(0,1,2)
c(1,1,2)
c(2,1,2)

Comment: for(j in 1:length(a))
{
  h[sum(b)+1] <- h[sum(b)+1]*choose(a[j],b[j])*p[j]^(b[j])*(1-p[j])^(a[j]-b[j])
}

Comment: Essentially, this is what I am trying to calculate. I have a pool of coins with different probabilities of flipping heads. I have a[1] coins that flip heads with probability p[1]. I have a[2] coins that flip heads with probability p[2]. Etc. I want to create a vector h where h[k+1] is the probability that if I were to flip all of my coins, I would get exactly k heads.

Comment: I just wrote it. That is the formula. I skipped the line:
h[sum(b)+1] <- 1
and a return(h), but otherwise, that code should give me the correct vector h.

Comment: Oh, I see where my code is going wrong. I should not be using c as a vector name since c is a function to create a vector. My bad.

Comment: I am not sure how to add code to a comment, so I will add it to the original post.

Comment: By the way, this is my first attempt at writing R code. I am not at all an R coder, but my job is looking to perform some statistical analysis functions, so I chose a project that I thought would be challenging and help me learn the ins-and-outs of the language. I decided to create a battle calculator for Axis and Allies. So far, I am just working on the probabilities for each outcome for a single round of combat. Next, I will work on the outcomes for full battles (I guess that would be Markov chains or semi-Markov chains... not too clear on the terminology).